# Windows on SSD and Ubuntu 17.04 on HDD

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

First of all I have an SSD with Windows 10 on it. I want to install Ubuntu 17.04 on a separate HDD.

I want to have the option to switch between Windows and Ubuntu. How do I install Ubuntu without losing Windows?

Comment: Simply install on the HDD. Don't touch the SSD. At the BIOS screen, you can select which device to use to boot.

Comment: Just be sure to install in same boot mode UEFI or BIOS. If Windows was pre-installed then UEFI, if upgrade from Windows 7 probably BIOS. And best to partition in advance and use Something Else. Grub will let you boot Windows if Secure boot is off and Windows fast start up is off (Windows may keep turning it on with updates). But with UEFI you can always directly boot. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu